# JavaCC parser function calls

Tags: javacc

I am making a parser which handles multiple line input.
The input program define some functions and main line is for the result.
For example, define function A which has { x+3 } (x is parameter for function A).
If main line call function A such as MAIN { A(1+3) }, then how can I call the function A to calculate the expression in the MAIN line.

Answer (score 2):

Normally your parser would translate the function to a representation that can be stored and interpreted later.  See my answer to [how do I implement loops (For) in javacc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546050/how-do-i-implement-loops-for-in-javacc) for more.